# Optimal file access speed while using of Visual Studio 2012 under Parallels, shared filesystem

Tags: visual-studio-2012, parallels

I am looking for a set of recommendat ways of using Visual Studio 2012 (or even older versions) under Parallels on Mac OS X.

The questions is not about the hardware itself, is about how to obtain the best level of performance while still running VS virtualized.

Where to keep the project files if you want them shared? Now they are on Mac partition and VS is accesing then using Parallels mounts. Even if this is on SSD drive, I am not very pleased about the speed. Is another option better?

The Windows-7 partition is a psysical one, not a virtual disk, same SSD drive as the OSX partition. Also, there is a secondary HDD in the machine but that's not used right now because it supposed to be much slower than the SSD.